# Group by with static columns and grouped columns

Tags: c#, linq

I'm use to sql, and not quite used to linq yet. May I ask how do I group columns based on a value, and group other columns to a list and make the other columns static?

For Example

```
People   |  Businesses   | StreetAddress
 John    |    Store 1    |  Hello Blvd.
 John    |    Store 2    |  Hello Blvd.
```

Produces

```
People   |       Businesses                 | StreetAddress
 John    |    ["Store 1", "Store 2"]        |  Hello Blvd.
```

My linq query to make Table 1

```
from x in ctx.People
join ownership in ctx.Ownerships
    on x.Id equals ownership.Owner_Id into ps
from ownership in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
join Business in ctx.Businesses
    on ownership.Business_Id equals  Business.Id into ps2
from Business in ps2.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new PersonDTO
{
    Id            = x.Id,
    Business      = Business.Name,
    StreetAddress = x.Addresses.FirstOrDefault().Line1
}
```

Comment: Using SQL Query ,i think its impossible, you need to use StoredProcedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you need to group by both People & StreetAddress.

```
 var result = data.GroupBy(x => new { x.People, x.StreetAddress })
                  .ToList()
                  .Select(x => new 
                            {
                                People = x.Key.People,
                                Business = String.Join(",",x.Select(z => z.Business),
                                StreetAddress x.Key.StreetAddress
                            });
```

**Edit:**
Fetch `Business` in a List.

```
 var result = data.GroupBy(x => new { x.People, x.StreetAddress })
                  .Select(x => new 
                            {
                                People = x.Key.People,
                                Business = x.Select(z => z.Business).ToList(),
                                StreetAddress x.Key.StreetAddress
                            });
```

Here, data is the data source you want to group.

Comment: Hi Rahul if I want it to be a list and not a string?

Comment: @Master- List as in? You mean List of `Business`?

Comment: Yes sorry that's what I meant. List of Strings which are businesses. So something like Business = z.Business.ToList()??

Comment: I got  'System.String Join(System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String]) trying the string method.

Comment: Sweet can you also update the string one, I think both answers are fabulous. Thank you! The string one doesnt quite work got that error from above.

Comment: @Master - Didn't get you. What is not working in first query? Is it throwing any exception?

Comment: @Master - Okay updated, the answer. Actually it tries to convert `String.Join` to SQL which obviously fails, so with `ToList()` we are running it first and then projecting.