# Group by with a select statement with Distinct list of Strings

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, mvvm

using the result I had from [Group by with static columns and grouped columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27449525/group-by-with-static-columns-and-grouped-columns/27449598?noredirect=1#comment43342016_27449598). It gave me a list of businesses but it is being displayed very weird when projected. May I ask how I go around this.

Business is displaying as `System.Linq.Enumerable+<Distinctiterator> System String`

```
var result = data.GroupBy(x => new { x.People, x.StreetAddress })
                  .Select(x => new 
                    {
                        People = x.Key.People,
                        Business = x.Select(z => z.Business).Distinct().ToList().ToString(),
                        StreetAddress x.Key.StreetAddress
                    });
```

Comment: What do you want it to look like?

Comment: My list of businesses, from using the example from the previous question ["Store 1", "Store 2"] but instead it displays that message System.linq...

Comment: What are you using to display the result?

Comment: RadGridView using MVVM Bindings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The displayed type name suggests that what's being displayed is still the result of the `Distinct()` method call. The code you posted wouldn't do that; it converts the result to a list and would produce output more like `System.Collections.Generic.List'1` (or something like that...I forget the exact representation and I think it uses the back-tick, but of course that's the markdown quote character so I can't show it exactly here).

Did you instead mean to create a real string out of the list, perhaps by using the `string.Join()` method?

That would look something like this:

```
result = data.GroupBy(x => new { x.People, x.StreetAddress })
              .Select(x => new 
                {
                    People = x.Key.People,
                    Business = string.Join(", ", x.Select(z => z.Business).Distinct()),
                    StreetAddress x.Key.StreetAddress
                });
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct @Peter Thank you, sorry I wrote the question poorly.